# How to fetch data from Siebel from Dotnet application and save it to SQL?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, siebel

I have a Dot Net Application from which I need to connect to the Siebel and fetch data from there and save the data to the SQL Server. How is all this process achievable ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all i is possible to setup Siebel on MS SQL Server (so you can have the data in SQL server already) :)
But back to your question:
Siebel has COM interface, and it is possible to use that in .Net (for example with C#) you should add the DLL files to the project:

- Interop.SiebelApplicationServer.dll
- Interop.SiebelBusObjectInterfaces.dll
- Interop.TWSiebelLib.dll

and then you can connect to Siebel with the code like the one below:

```
using SiebelBusObjectInterfaces;

....    
var app = new SiebelBusObjectInterfaces.SiebelDataControl();
app.Login(connectionString, userName, password);
```

Comment: Could you help me with my question. http://serverfault.com/questions/640496/setup-siebel-serevr-on-my-mac